# Can't find Utf8JsonWriter.WriteRawValue() in .NET 5 SDK 5.0.400

Tags: .net-core

[This pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/54254) added the `WriteRawValue` method to the `Utf8JsonWriter` class in the .NET runtime repo on 3 July 2021. The next .NET release (see [release history](https://versionsof.net/core/) and [the version tag on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/releases/tag/v5.0.9)) was on 10 August. It's version 5.0.9, SDK version 5.0.400. After installing this version, the above-mentioned method is still missing from the `Utf8JsonWriter` class.

I am banging my head in the wall and asking why?

Comment: According to the github history, this is targeted for .NET 6.0.0.

Comment: @TimRoberts , thanks a lot! I never actually took a look at the history comments but now I see it was added to the 6.0.0 milestone. I guess that means I should find it in the next .NET 6 preview. If you'd like, answer the question, and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the github history, this is targeted for .NET 6.0.0.